# String values manipulation

Tags: excel, vba

Sir I have a set of similar values in a column in different rows in Excel worksheet for e.g. say ABC Company, ABC Company., ABC Comp., ABC Com. I would like this similar values to be converted into one value

Comment: Could you make a pseudo excel table with the `|` and the `_` character? 

Something like this: `ABC Company | ABC Company | ....`

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what exactly you need, but this is a starter:

This VBA method will loop over your cells, concat the values and print it to the debug console or set another cell with the value.

```
Sub concat()

    Dim rng As Range
    Dim row As Range
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim str As String

    Set rng = Range("B3:B6")

    For Each row In rng.Rows
      For Each cell In row.Cells
        ' This is the result string:
        str = str & " " & cell.Value
      Next cell
    Next row

    ' Print the concatantion string to the console:
    Debug.Print (str)
    ' or just set the value in another cell:
    Cells(10, 10).Value = str
End Sub
```